# How to separate 2 distributions knowing histogram?

Tags: math, image-processing, computer-vision, stat, threshold

I have big set of integer numbers (colors) from 0 to 255. I know that some of them should become black, other go to white. I can plot histogram of them and there always will be 2 peaks of black color at left and white color at right. How to find optimal threshold to separate these distributions?

I found normal constant threshold, but sometimes it's too high. This task seems like not so hard, is there some algorithm to solve it just in time for each set??

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The method of Otsu performs very well on bimodal data sets.

Comment: "The task seems not so hard": anyway, in the third case 170 seems equally possible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what is this method of Otsu??

Comment: Have a read here... https://learnopencv.com/otsu-thresholding-with-opencv/

Comment: Or with **ImageMagick** in Terminal `magick input.png -auto-threshold OTSU result.png`

Comment: @ДмитрийПасько:  do you have access to a web search engine ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I dunno what it is, but now I'm trying to use Otsu method, it's perspectively

Answer (score 0):

You can consider Expectation–Maximization algorithm.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm